# Can't have data in variable on function querysnapchot in firebase

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

i can't have my data in my variable "nom" in the function querysnapchot for my action "toggle name".
querySnapshot.docs[0].data(); have a data of course.

```
    var nom = '';
    firebase.firestore().collection('Users').where("Id", "==",res.user.uid)
    .get()
    .then(function(querySnapshot) {
      if (querySnapshot.size > 0) {
        // Contents of first document
        nom = querySnapshot.docs[0].data();
      } else {
        console.log("No such document!");
      }
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
        console.log("Error getting documents: ", error);
    });

    console.log(nom);
    const action = { type: "TOGGLE_NAME", value: nom };
    this.props.dispatch(action)
    this.props.navigation.navigate('Navigation')
```

Comment: Hey! Can you add a comment in the `if`-part? `if (querySnapshot.size > 0) {
        nom = querySnapshot.docs[0].data();console.log(nom);
      }` I suspect that the get()-function is async, thus your log is just performed before the result is stored in nom.

Answer (score 1):

The Firestore APIs are asynchronous and return immediately before the query is complete. The `then` callback is invoked some time later with the results.  This is essentially true for any API that returns a promise.

You can only use the results of the query **inside** the callback.  You can't use them in code that follows the query, as that code will execute immediately, before the query is complete.  Place your code that depends on the query results inside the callback.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I add a .then() after my promise and it's work